# Can't store user_id into another table in flutter

Tags: flutter

I need to create a table that will add the user_id as another data in the table. But somehow my solution does not work.

The table user looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE user(
      user_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
      username TEXT NOT NULL,
      password TEXT NOT NULL,
      f_name TEXT NOT NULL,
      l_name TEXT NOT NULL,
      email TEXT NOT NULL,
      phone INTEGER NOT NULL
    )
```

After the login, the user have to fill in a form, the data goes to the table, flowerbook:

```
CREATE TABLE flowerbook(
      book_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
      deliver_date TEXT NOT NULL,
      arrangement TEXT NOT NULL,
      flower_type TEXT NOT NULL,
      user_id INTEGER NOT NULL
    )
```

I tried doing this, on the submit button of the form:

```
onPressed: () {
                            Flowerbook flowerbook = Flowerbook(
                              deliver_date: dateController.text,
                              flower_type: checkboxController.text,
                              arrangement: dropdownController.text,
                              user_id: widget.user.user_id,
                            );

                            Flowerbook.register(flowerbook);

                          },
```

But I still get this error:

> [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: DatabaseException(NOT NULL constraint failed: flowerbook.user_id (code 1299 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_NOTNULL)) sql 'INSERT OR REPLACE INTO flowerbook (book_id, deliver_date, arrangement, flower_type, user_id) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, NULL)' args [1/1/2023 12:00:00, Box, Carnation]

As you can see, the delivery_date, flower_type, and arrangement is successfully added as an argument. But user_id is NULL.

What seems to be the problem here?

I did log the `widget.user.user_id`, and it is indeed `NULL`.

Maybe there's something wrong at my menu page? Here's my code:

```
final List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
      FormPage(user: widget.user),
      OrderPage(user: widget.user),
      AccountPage(user: widget.user),
    ];
```

Comment: log the `widget.user.user_id` in `onPressed`. It is likely null. You'll have to trace through your code to see why its null. Provided code seems correct. The issue is elsewhere.

Comment: I checked, and you're right, it is NULL. Where do you think I should check next to trace the problem @Madushan

Comment: check where you're assigning the user_id and make sure that code path is executed (try a breakpoint) and make sure it is the correct instance you're setting the user_id on.